# Negative duration with Boost Chrono's process_real_cpu_clock

Tags: c++, boost, time, c++-chrono

I am trying to use Boost.Chrono to measure CPU time of my code. My C++ code for this is given below. The problem is that I sometimes get negative durations as output. This happens when I use "process_real_cpu_clock". When I use "steady_clock" the problem does not appear. Some of the outputs I  took are following:

> time for 1st implemention:360 ms
>
> time for 2nd implementation:-3284.97 ms
>
> ---
>
> time for 1st implemention:360 ms
>
> time for 2nd implementation:1010 ms
>
> ---
>
> time for 1st implemention:-3924.97 ms
>
> time for 2nd implementation:1010 ms

Only the second one is as expected. I guess the problem was about overflow of the duration, but in the third output, time for 1st implementation should be around 1/3 of the time for 2nd implemenation, then there should not be overflow if I can see time for 2nd implemenation. (I am using Boost 1.54, and working with Ubuntu on VirtualBox)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/process_cpu_clocks.hpp>

int main() {

int x,y,result,runs;
srand(time(NULL));
runs=1e7;


boost::chrono::process_real_cpu_clock::time_point start, start2; 
boost::chrono::process_real_cpu_clock::time_point end, end2;

start= boost::chrono::process_real_cpu_clock::now();

    for (int i=0;i<runs;i++) {

        x=rand() %100 +1;
        y=rand() %100 +1;
        auto dummy=x*y;
        result=(result+dummy)%50;
        } 
end=boost::chrono::process_real_cpu_clock::now();
boost::chrono::process_real_cpu_clock::duration diff=end-start;

start2= boost::chrono::process_real_cpu_clock::now();

    for (int i=0;i<(3*runs);i++) {

        x=rand() %100 +1;
        y=rand() %100 +1;
        auto dummy=x*y;
        result=(result+dummy)%50;

        } 
end2=boost::chrono::process_real_cpu_clock::now();

boost::chrono::process_real_cpu_clock::duration diff2=end2-start2;

     std::cout << "time for 1st implemention:"<<boost::chrono::duration <double, boost::milli> (diff).count()<< " ns" << std::endl;
     std::cout << "time for 2nd implementation:"<<boost::chrono::duration <double, boost::milli> (diff2).count()<< " ns" << std::endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure this is the code? `start1` and `end1` are unused here. Proper factoring of the code avoids error-prone situations like this. I've added such a factored solution to my answer (it might be too generic for your taste).

Comment: You are right. `start1` and `end1` were there from previous version of the code. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you mistakenly used `boost::milli`  (which is just a general purpose ratio from `Boost Ratio`).

You want to use `duration_cast` with the units from chrono:

```
std::cout << "time for 1st implemention:" << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(diff).count() << " ns\n";
std::cout << "time for 2nd implementation:" << duration_cast<nanoseconds>(diff2).count() << " ns\n";
```

Here's my take on it (choosing milliseconds for readability):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46fa203f2a66a2e1)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/process_cpu_clocks.hpp>

using namespace boost::chrono;

template <typename R, typename P>
    static std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, duration<R,P> const& d) {
        return os << boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(d).count() << "ms";
    }

template <typename Clock = boost::chrono::process_cpu_clock, typename F, typename... Args>
nanoseconds bench(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    auto start = Clock::now();

    volatile auto force = std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    (void) force;

    return Clock::now() - start;
}

long long foo(int runs) {
    long long result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        int x = rand() % 100 + 1;
        int y = rand() % 100 + 1;
        auto dummy = x * y;
        result = (result + dummy) % 50;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    std::cout << "1st method: " << bench(foo, 1e7)   << "\n";
    std::cout << "2nd method: " << bench(foo, 3e7) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
1st method: 340ms
2nd method: 1010ms
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @sehe, but the outputs I get are still weird. Some of them are like these:
`1st method: 503ms
2nd method: -1310ms`
    `1st method: -971ms
2nd method: 1574ms`
    `1st method: 503ms
2nd method: 99ms`

Comment: I can only wonder about an implementation bug/anomaly under VBox (try with/without guest additions, accelarations/CPU/chipset virtualization options?) and you could file a ticket at Boost Chrono